# how to fetch all the data pushed using history.push in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to fetch all the states pushed in history api using js, I can get them viewing the browser history but I want to fetch them and use their data somewhere in my code

I pushed the history state using history api - history.push({state:"testOne"})

like the above there have been so many state pushed I just need to fetch them

Answer (score 0):

Does your code have control to when `history.push` is being used? If yes, you can make a wrapper/spy function

```
let list = [];
history._push = history.push;
history.push = function(...args){
   list.push(args);
   return history._push(...args);
}
```

`list` now contains all states pushed